# Dual monitors detected as one

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga

I have 2 monitors connected with VGA. However, ubuntu only detects one monitor, and the same thing shows on both displays.

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I get these 2 monitors to act as 2 separate monitors?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution? :o(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have connected your screens to the correct ports. For example, if you have a graphic card, make sure that your screen is connected to the graphic card. If this fails then, you this problem might be drivers related:

If you haven't done so already, you need to install additional driver, open on :

*System Settings > Additional Drivers*.

If this doesn't help then try:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

And restart:

```
reboot
```

Then Open *Settings > Displays > Detect Displays* then also unchecked the checkbox labelled *Mirror Displays*.

Lastly you can try to reinstall the latest nvidia drivers:

```
Run sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: The first command results in: `mv: target '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup' is not a directory`